# How to convert ActiveRecord Relation object generated with group in query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In our rails 4.2 app, the search result returns in `@models`. This `@models` is a chained `ActiveRecord Relation` object.

```
@models=#<PaymentRequestx::PaymentRequest::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x000000064e71a8>
```

We just add a query with `group`. Now the operations on `@models`, such `@models.size`, @models.sum('amount') becomes invalid. Both `@models.size (or count)` and `@models.sum('amount')` return hash object instead. If we want to keep our code unchanged, is there a way we can convert `@models` into a regular object which we can apply normal `.count` and `.sum` on it? It is hard to make code to process 2 types of search data stored in `@models`.

Comment: Use `@model.group(...).to_a` if that's an option performance-wise. This will unify the result. You'll just need to change the sum to `sum(&:amount)`

Comment: I am looking for a solution which converts the output format instead of changing the code of `sum` and `size`.

Comment: there isn't one. These are two different queries.

One ugly workaround that I can think of: `Model.where(id: @models).count`